# How to add mouseover in li after a click on li using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I run the program. I got the first hover effect in each li element. After that I clicked on one li then I changed its border color to red. After that my hover effect of li is not working.

After I added one more ul in the existing code. Then, I clicked li of the first ul and after that, I clicked li of 2nd ul. How can I activate both li of first and second ul?

```js
$("#id_of_ul").on("click", "li", function () {
  $(this).toggleClass("active").siblings(".active").removeClass("active");;
});
$("#id_of_ul1").on("click", "li", function () {
  $(this).toggleClass("active").siblings(".active").removeClass("active");;
});
```

```css
    ul li:hover {
  border-color: #cc4e00
}

.result_hover {
  border-color: #cc4e00;
}

.cls {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
}

li.active {
 border-color: #cc4e00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul class="mt-1 mb-0" id="id_of_ul">
    <li id="a1" class="cls">
      <span class="spnCls" id="spn_a1"><img src="img" alt="" class="img-fluid"></span>
      <label>1</label>
    </li>
    <li id="a2" class="cls">
      <span class="spnCls" id="spn_a2"><img src="img" alt="" class="img-fluid"></span>
      <label>2</label>
    </li>
    <li id="a3" class="cls">
      <span class="spnCls" id="spn_a3"><img src="img" alt="" class="img-fluid"></span>
      <label>3</label>
    </li>
    <li id="a4" class="cls">
      <span class="spnCls" id="spn_a4"><img src="img" alt="" class="img-fluid"></span>
      <label>4</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
<ul class="mt-1 mb-0" id="id_of_ul1">
        <li id="a11" class="cls">
          <span class="spnCls" id="spn_a11"><img src="img" alt="" class="img-fluid"></span>
          <label>1</label>
        </li>
        <li id="a12" class="cls">
          <span class="spnCls" id="spn_a12"><img src="img" alt="" class="img-fluid"></span>
          <label>2</label>
        </li>
        <li id="a13" class="cls">
          <span class="spnCls" id="spn_a13"><img src="img" alt="" class="img-fluid"></span>
          <label>3</label>
        </li>
        <li id="a14" class="cls">
          <span class="spnCls" id="spn_a14"><img src="img" alt="" class="img-fluid"></span>
          <label>4</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue is because using `css()` applies the styling to the element using an inline `style` attribute which will override any rules from an external stylesheet. Exactly how you overcome this in your situation depends on your use case. If you need a specific example, please add a more complete example of the JS, as well as the relevant HTML.

Comment: I added my full program,html,css and js

Comment: Just add a class.... do not style elements directly onclick, add selected class, remove the selected class from the other elements

Comment: Yes. It's working for me. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the color directly on the element will blow away the CSS because of specificity.

Just toggle a class on the element that was clicked.

```js
$("#id_of_ul").on("click", "li", function () {
  $(this).toggleClass("active").siblings(".active").removeClass("active");;
});
```

```css
ul li:hover {
  border-color: #cc4e00
}

.result_hover {
  border-color: #cc4e00;
}

.cls {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
}

li.active {
 border-color: #cc4e00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul class="mt-1 mb-0" id="id_of_ul">
    <li id="a1" class="cls">
      <span class="spnCls" id="spn_a1"><img src="img" alt="" class="img-fluid"></span>
      <label>1</label>
    </li>
    <li id="a2" class="cls">
      <span class="spnCls" id="spn_a2"><img src="img" alt="" class="img-fluid"></span>
      <label>2</label>
    </li>
    <li id="a3" class="cls">
      <span class="spnCls" id="spn_a3"><img src="img" alt="" class="img-fluid"></span>
      <label>3</label>
    </li>
    <li id="a4" class="cls">
      <span class="spnCls" id="spn_a4"><img src="img" alt="" class="img-fluid"></span>
      <label>4</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```